# Is there a function to combine the population of smaller areas into larger areas?

Tags: r, join, dplyr

I am attempting to join two data sets, one for crash data and the other for population by area. The crash data looks like the following and has 7 regions. Lets say the data looks like this and is called "crashes"

| region | fatal | severe | minor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Canterbury | 222 | 833 | 1022 |
| West Coast | 23 | 109 | 321 |
| Southland | 56 | 112 | 192 |
| Nelson | 63 | 156 | 345 |
| Tasman | 33 | 88 | 111 |
| Otago | 121 | 489 | 701 |
| Marlborough | 31 | 91 | 109 |

The population by areas looks like: "population"

| TA | Population |
| --- | --- |
| Christchurch | 211022 |
| Selwyn | 23000 |
| Ashburton | 56011 |
| Timaru | 63891 |
| Queenstown-Lakes | 45111 |
| Central Otago | 12113 |
| Clutha | 3111 |

For some reference, I would like to join the population to the crash data but first must combine some of the TA to the bigger regions. For region Canterbury = Christchurch + Selwyn + Ashburton + Timaru.
For the Otago region = Queenstown-Lakes + Central Otago + Clutha. I would like to combine the populations of these TA's that would then join the crashes data according to the region the TA's are in. Sorry for the messy example I am unsure how to go about in making a good example for this sort of data.

Comment: But where is the table of rows saying that a given area is in a given region? (And then, how would you explain how to use it? And then, what relational operation is that? And then, where are you stuck?) PS [mre] [ask]

Answer (score 0):

I think a way to do this is by building a translation vector for small region to big region and use it to add a region column in population on which you can group to have region population and them make a join of the table.

```
small_region <- c('Christchurch', 'Selwyn', 'Ashburton', 'Timaru',
                  'Queenstown-Lakes', 'Central Otago', 'Clutha')
small_to_big <- structure(c(rep("canterbury", 4), rep("Oregon", 3)),
                          names = small_region)

population %>% 
  mutate(region = small_to_big[TA]) %>% 
  group_by(region) %>% 
  summarise(Population = sum(Population)) %>% 
  right_join(crashes, by = "region")
```